# Creating a heatmap on R using leaflet function add_heatmap() or addHeatmap()

Tags: r, leaflet, plotly, heatmap, r-plotly

I am trying to create a plot with heatmap using plotly add_heatmap() function, but it generates an error message saying **Error: Must supply `z` attribute** I referred to [this site](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/exploring-london-crime-with-r-heat-maps/) for addHeatmap() function provided by *leaflet.extras* package.

The following code only displays dots from addCircles() and outputs a warning message and a map as shown below:

```
final_df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(
    lng = final_df$long,
    lat = final_df$lat,
    popup = final_df$station_name
  ) %>% addHeatmap(lng = final_df$long, lat = final_df$lat, radius=5)
```

[image: warning message]
[image: dot map]

I have tried a different function add_heatmap() from leaflet which does not display any maps and generates an error.

```
final_df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(
    lng = final_df$long,
    lat = final_df$lat,
    popup = final_df$station_name
  ) %>% add_heatmap(lng = final_df$long, lat = final_df$lat)
```

[image: error message]

Anyone faced a similar issue and created a heatmap on R?

Comment: In the Warning message for addHeatmap() it informs you there are invalid lat/lng coords in your data. Have you tried removing NA values from your lat/lng columns. `dplyr::filter(!is.na(lat))`

Comment: I wanted to add that although its a warning, it will not render the points with `NA` values, but the map will still render. Should filter as Jumble said, or `filter_at(vars(lng, lat), all_vars(!is.na(.)))` That warning about being ignored was misleading to myself. If any coords are invalid, ALL coords are ignored, not just the invalid ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove addCircles part and try:

```
library(leaflet.extras)

final_df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addHeatmap(lng = final_df$long, lat = final_df$lat, blur = 40, max = 0.05, radius = 15)
```